# Form With Unlimited Fields

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

[image: Mockup of the form I'm trying to submit through PHP in rows]

I have a form that has an [Add Fields] option making it possible to add virtually unlimited Item Numbers and Descriptions.

These fields are named: `item[]` and `desc[]` (brackets for arrays).

My question is, how would I submit this information with PHP and MySQL so that each row (item and description) is submitted as it's own row in the database?

I've tried multiple methods like submitting item[0] and desc[0] together with no avail :(

Thanks for all of your help in advance!

EDIT: Below is what I've been trying to use... (Sorry, not that great with arrays...)

```
$count = 0
foreach ($_POST['item'] as $item) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO items (item, desc) VALUES ('" . $item[$count] . "', '" . $_POST['desc'][$count] . "')";
        // Script simplified as it is quite complex.
    if ($query_result) {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does submitting `item[0]` and `desc[0]` together fail?

Comment: Use a for or foreach loop. Also show us your PHP code that you tried.

Comment: Funny - I'm actually building an almost identical system right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can loop through any one of the input field using foreach loop and then access other fields.

```
foreach($_POST['item'] as $key => $item){
    //your code
    $desc = $_POST['desc'][$key];
}
```

EDIT : as per your code script will be like

```
$count = 0
foreach ($_POST['item'] as $key => $item) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO items (item, desc) VALUES ('" . $item . "', '" . $_POST['desc'][$key] . "')";
        // Script simplified as it is quite complex.
    if ($query_result) {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this give me $item[0] and $desc[0], $item[1] and $desc[1], etc?

Comment: Yes, It will give u all of your rows in submitted form.

Comment: Although this works - I would recommend doing a bit differently... this way can be slightly confusing to look at and comprehend (ie. quickly seeing where the value of desc came from) ... see my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

To further help you out, I might suggest the following.

Name your fields like so:

```
line[1][item]
line[1][desc]

line[2][item]
line[2][desc]

etc...
```

Then in PHP the data will make more 'sense' when viewing it:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach ($_POST['line'] as $line => $vals) {
  $item = $vals['item']; /* do some kind of input validation here */
  $desc = $vals['desc']; /* do some kind of input validation here */

  /* if no errors, continue */

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `items` (`item`,`desc`) VALUES ('$item', '$desc')";
  if (mysql_query ($sql)) {
    $count++;
  }
}
?>
```

I find this method to be more flexible.  Just my two cents.

Luke